# MultiIndex (multilevel) column names from Dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a rather messy dataframe in which I need to assign first 3 rows as a multilevel column names.
This is my dataframe and I need index 3, 4 and 5 to be my multiindex column names.
[image]

For example, 'MINERAL TOTAL' should be the level 0 until next item; 'TRATAMIENTO (ts)' should be level 1 until 'LEY Cu(%)' comes up.

What I need actually is try to emulate what pandas.read_excel does when 'header' is specified with multiple rows.

Please help!

I am trying this, but no luck at all:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=df.iloc[3:, :].to_numpy(), columns=tuple(df.iloc[:3, :].to_numpy(dtype='str')))
```

Comment: If `pd.read_excel` does what you need, you could always do something like `dataframe.to_excel('tmpfile.xlsx')` followed by `pd.read_excel`

Comment: I cannot.. this dataframe is read from an excel that has multiple sheets and tables (even in the same sheet) and I have thousands of excel and I cannot read 100 times every excel (+1000) in order to get what I need (too much time).

Comment: Is `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays` what you want?
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html

Comment: Instead of adding a screenshot, consider adding some code that replicates part of the data - say the first 3 columns and 10 rows.  That way it's easier to test any solutions when writing an answer.  You should read this article on how to write a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a list of row indexes to the `header` argument and pandas will combine them into a `MultiIndex`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('ExcelFile.xlsx', header=[0,1,2])
```

By default, pandas will read in the top row as the sole header row. You can pass the `header` argument into `pandas.read_excel()` that indicates how many rows are to be used as headers. This can be either an int, or list of ints. See the `pandas.read_excel()` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) for more information.

As you mentioned you are unable to use `pandas.read_excel()`. However, if you do already have a DataFrame of the data you need, you can use `pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays()`. First you would need to specify an array of the header rows which in your case would look something like:

```py
array = [df.iloc[0].values, df.iloc[1].values, df.iloc[2].values]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(array)
```

The only issue here is this includes the "NaN" values in the new MultiIndex header. To get around this, you could create some function to clean and forward fill the lists that make up the array.

Although not the prettiest, nor the most efficient, this could look something like the following (off the top of my head):

```py
def forward_fill(iterable):
    return pd.Series(iterable).ffill().to_list()

zero = forward_fill(df.iloc[0].to_list())
one = forward_fill(df.iloc[1].to_list())
two = one = forward_fill(df.iloc[2].to_list())

array = [zero, one, two]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(array)
```

You may also wish to drop the header rows (in this case rows 0 and 1) and reindex the DataFrame.

```py
df.drop(index=[0,1,2], inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I cannot use pandas.read_excel... I need to emulate what pandas.read_excel does when I pass the header parameter

Comment: Apologies, I overlooked that part of your question. Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since columns are also indices, you can just transpose, set index levels, and transpose back.

```py
df.T.fillna(method='ffill').set_index([3, 4, 5]).T
```